# How do I make a link for data/post from mysql?

Tags: php, html, mysql, get

I have the ID for every post/record from mysql, I don't know how to make a special link for them. I asked similiar question and they told me to use $_GET but I don't know really how, would be helpful if you could type the code or tell me how.Also how can I, when I create that link echo that specific post on that specific link? Here's the code.

```
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $Nick = $row["Nick"];
    $Mail = $row["Mail"];
    $Message = $row["Message"];

    $ID = $row["IDNumber"];



    echo '<div style ="text-align:center; font-size: 100%; margin-top: 9%; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">' . "Nick: " . $Nick  . '</div>';

    echo '<div style ="text-align:center; font-size: 100%; margin-top: 9%; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><a href="?id=' . $id .'"' . "Message: " . $Message  . '</a></div>';
    }
 } else {
echo "0 results";
}



?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I give a special link to every post in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31662730/how-can-i-give-a-special-link-to-every-post-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

You can do like that:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['id'])) {

    // id index exists
    $id = $_GET['id'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE id = " . $id;
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
         echo "post does not exist";
    }
    else {
       //display data like you did
    }
}
else {
   //your old code
}
```

The url will be something like yourpagename.php?id=1